# controller name made up by two segments

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In ASP.NET MVC4 Web API, i want to support a kind of url:

```
api/{part1}/{part2}/{id}
```

whose controller is {part1}{part2}, e.g.

```
       url                  controller              class
api/ch01/products/         ch01products     ch01productscontroller
api/ch12/customers         ch12customers    ch12customerscontroller
api/books/page/5           bookspage        bookspagecontroller
```

Can I do this in MapHttpRoute? Something like

```
// in WebApiConfig.Register
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("", "api/{part1}/{part2}/{id}", new { controller = ? "{part1}" + "{part2}" ?, id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a custom route handler: http://geekswithblogs.net/sankarsan/archive/2009/01/18/developing-custom-routehandler.aspx